# Which browser specific CSS3 necessary for mobile website

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, css, nokia

As we develop our mobile version website, I am wondering how many of the browser specific CSS3 versions are necessary.  The plan is for only smaller handheld devices to be sent to the mobile version, iPad, Galaxy and other tablets will stay on the main website.

In particular I am wondering about box-shadow, border-radius and gradient css support.

I have been combing the wonderful world of google and come up with the list below, of which browser specific versions might be necessary to cover the bulk of smart phones.

**-webkit-** for box-shadow

**-webkit-** for border-radius

**-webkit-**, **-o-**, **-moz-** for gradient

Can anyone confirm my list?  Or tell me which ones I didn't list might be necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [css3please.com](http://css3please.com/) to get all the possible prefixes for most of the commonly used css3 features.

As for mobile; you will not need the IE prefixes (opera has mobile browsers etc.)

Don't forget to always specify a non-prefixed version, regardless of if its already supported by some browsers, because it will be in the future, and the prefixed versions will go ignored.

To look up more specific information about property support in different browsers you could look them up on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)

Comment: Thanks.  That webpage is an interesting demo of the various css, but I am already aware of the variations.  I am trying to find the minimum number of variations necessary to cover the maximum number of smart phones for the three specific css3 items.

Comment: @Tom in that case you'll need all except the internet explorer prefix `-ms-` for max compatibility. But if you don't need support you can use caniuse.com to look up specific properties and their support in different browsers (including mobile): http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: Thanks again, caniuse.com was one of the references I used for my preliminary list.

Comment: @Tom Then I think you're all set, caniuse is by far the best reference for property support. To get more specific information you're going to have to test it yourself on all relevant platforms, but the information on caniuse is pretty solid and you should trust it.